# Trouble solving the PDE $-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-2u$ using method of characteristics

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following (quasilinear) PDE using the Methode of Characteristics:

$-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-2u$

The Cauchy Data is $u(x,0)=x$

What I did:
In this case $\Gamma$ is the x-Axis, $\Gamma=${$(t,0):t \in \mathbb{R}$}.
Next step was to get a parametrization of

$S:=${$(\overline{x}(t),\overline {y}(t),\overline{u}(t)): t \in \mathbb{R}$}
,where $\overline {u}(t)=u(\overline{x}(t),\overline{y}(t))$

In my case $\overline{x}(t)=t$, and $\overline{y}(t)=0$.

This means $S:=${$(t,0,t): t \in \mathbb{R}$}
After that I tried to pick some Point $p=(x_0,y_0)$, and calculate
$\frac{\partial u (x_0,y_0)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u (x_0,y_0)}{\partial y}$
I decided to start with p=(1,0):

The problem now is, that I don't know $u(x,y)$. I only have $u(1,0)=x$, and working with it yields $\frac{\partial u (1,0)}{\partial x}=1$ and $\frac{\partial u (x,0)}{\partial y}=0$. This result seems kinda odd. Can someone show me what I did wrong/how to do it right?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by what you are doing. Why don't you solve the ODEs $$\frac{dx}{-u} = \frac{dy}{1} = \frac{du}{-2u}$$ first, then apply the ICs? Hint: the result should be $u e^{2y} = C_{1}$, $u - 2x = C_{2}$.

Comment: @mattos I was a little bit confused, how to solve the PDE. I tried to replicate the motivation of the method of characteristics and struggled with it. This is what I tried to do. But I think, I did understand it now.

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully the answer by JJacquelin below answered all your questions then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-2u$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{-u}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{-2u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{-2u}$
$$e^{2y}u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{-u}=\frac{du}{-2u}$ :
$$u-2x=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{e^{2y}u=F(u-2x)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the boundary condition).

Condition : $u(x,0)=x$
$$e^{2(0)}x=F(x-2x)\quad\implies\quad F(-x)=x$$
Let $X=-x$
$$F(X)=-X$$
The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=u-2x$ :
$$e^{2y}u=-(u-2x)$$
$$e^{2y}u+u=2x$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{2x}{1+e^{2y}}}$$
This is the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.